# How to render a4j:outputPanel programmatically

Tags: java, jsf

Is it possible to rerender a `a4j:outputPanel` programmatically from java method?

Answer (score 1):

You can keep a poll and just set some flag from method if that flag has been caught in poll as set just render the panel